# Laravel Deployments Idea

Tags: php, laravel, devops, continuous-deployment

I am developing a Laravel application for a client company of mine. That company has a server guy. In the middle of the development process, I asked him to set up a server for the application. But he set up a server without any kind of automated deployments procedure instead he gave me a C-Pannel to deploy the changes manually. The application became so complex and now manual deployments became a very tedious task. I am manually building js and css and uploading them to the server. After a heated argument with him, I finally made him work on automated deployments. Instead of properly putting deployments he has put it this way.

```php
 
<?php
//app/Console/Commands/GitPull.php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class GitPull extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'git:pull';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Get updates from git server';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        exec('git pull origin master');
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
app/Console/Kernel.php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
       Commands\GitPull::class, 
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('git:pull')
                  ->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Basically he has put a scheduler to execute git pull every minute. Is this the correct way to put deployments? What are the drawbacks in this way? Do the deployments have to be dependent on the application? Is it possible to add automated deployments without the help of the laravel framework? I am not very familiar with dev-ops.

Also, my source code is in bitbucket. I am ready to answer any questions regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I certainly would not use a Laravel command to run deployments. Automated deployments can be as simple or complex as needed, but here are some things I expect a build agent to do:

- Listen to changes to master to do a production deploy
- Run tests (and alert and stop deployment if they fail)
- Build my static assets (js/css/etc)
- Copy code to server (several ways to do this)
- Run migrations
- Restart queues so they are running with latest code

Since you're on bitbucket you could look into pipelines to do your ci/cd.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I will look into bitbucket pipelines.